# How to update array specific attribute of an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check an array and find the array that contains a certain thing

I have a cartarray that contains these values

```
  {id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"}

  {id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"}

  {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "3"}

  {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"}

  {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"}
```

each of the object represent a product 
what I really want to do is prevent duplication of id so if the id are the same, I want to consolidate the quantities. so before I add a new product object of this format

```
{id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "7"}
```

I want to check if there is similar productid in the cartarray

```
var arrayLength = cartarry.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
    if (cartarry[i] == product.id ){
        console.log("we got a match")           
        var updatedquantity = quantity + parseInt(product.quantity) 
    }
}
```

I tried couple of different method but unsuccessful. How can i find the matching id and update the quantity ? I hope i am clear in my description

Comment: It would be much more efficient to store the IDs as keys of an object so you don't have to search for them every time. The value could be the index of the associated object in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consolidate your product quantities by id you want to use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
let data = [
  {id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"},
  {id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"},
  {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "3"},
  {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"},
  {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"}
];

data = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const foundItem = acc.find(_item => _item.id === item.id);
  if(foundItem) {
    foundItem.quantity = Number(item.quantity) + Number(foundItem.quantity) + '';
  }
  else {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(data);

//0: {id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "2"}
//1: {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "5"}
```

**UPD**. With the help of the `reduce` method we want to get a processed copy of original data array. The output array is being formed as `acc` accumulator value, which is initially an empty array (this is regulated by the last parameter of `reduce`: `[]`). Each item of initial data set is being considered separately as `item` local variable inside a callback, and we are changing `acc` in accordance with the current `item` contents. We are trying to find current `item` in current `acc` array by `id` to consolidate quantities. Otherwise, if current `item` is unique for current `acc` array, we are pushing current `item` to `acc`.

Comment: Thank you.I am new to javascript and I looked at Array.prototype.reduce. can you please help me explain your code

Answer (score 1):

I'll chip away at the problem.  The line

```
if (cartarray[i] == product.id) {
```

should be

```
if (cartarray[i].id == product.id) {
```

Also, if there can be only zero or one cartarray entry that matches product.id, consider putting a break after your accumulator.

Comment: My answer used String::equals() rather than '==', and someone edited it to use '=='.  The '==' operator when applied to objects only tests object identity, not object equality.  Java runtimes use a String cache such that two Strings with the same content would actually be the same object.  But (a) I don't know if this is guaranteed in all runtimes, and (b) I would expect equals() to take advantage of this if it were.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayLength = cartarry.length;
var match = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
    if (cartarry[i].id == product.id ) {
       console.log("we got a match")

       cartarry[i].quantity += parseInt(product.quantity);
       match = true;
       break; // because this can only happen once per array
    }
}
if (!match) {
    // add it to the array
}
```

There's not a whole lot of information in your post so I guessed at a couple things. The key details are:

- You can't just compare `product.id` to `cartarry[i]`. `cartarry[i]` contains an object with the fields `id`, `name`, `price`, and `quantity`. You have to make use of those fields for the comparison, as well as updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
 var grouped = [];
 var array = [{id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"},
      {id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"},
      {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "3"},
      {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"},
      {id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"}]

array.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!this[o.id]) {
        this[o.id] = { id: o.id, name:o.name, price:o.price, quantity: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[o.id]);
    }
    this[o.id].quantity += parseInt(o.quantity);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```